# R paste two string with an equal sign between it : "stringA" = "stringB"

Tags: r, string, paste

I have 2 arrays in R,

One is

```
derive = c("excellent","bon","bad");
```

The other is

```
couleurs = c("lightgreen","green","red");
```

I want to have the following result :

```
result = c("excellent"="lightgreen","bon"="green","bad"="red");
```

Using the paste function, I always get the whole result between "", whereas the "=" must be out of the "".

I tried using sep=' " " ' but it create a string with escaped "".

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: `names(couleurs) <- derive` gives the same result in the object `couleures` as your definition `result = ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `names` for this:

```
derive        <- c("excellent","bon","bad")
couleurs      <- c("lightgreen","green","red")
result        <- couleurs
names(result) <- derive
```

Comment: Indeed this gives the same result, result does not look exactly like what I expected but it is interpreted by R the same way. And that's what mattered.